# How to verify that the request is from a specific web app

Tags: javascript, php, security, cordova

So I've got a web API for my (javascript) web app. The app is wrapped in Cordova and distributed on iOS and Android.

I would prefer to keep the data access limited (keep third parties from using my API). But how would I do this? I do not require (nor want) the user to create an account so the app itself must somehow verify that its the app sending the request, and not someone else.

But how?

Comment: Have your app generate a token understood by the server - change the token per user or such and encrypt it

Comment: That's easily doable, but if someone plugs in their phone to their laptop/computer through USB and decompiles the files they would find the (trimmed and obfuscated) javascript files generating the token, which wouldn't be incredibly difficult to refactor, so it feels like I'd need something more

Comment: Perhaps generate a token that is specific to the phone?

Comment: Web service APIs are by nature, usually client agnostic.  You face the same issues web servers have when trying to verify a client based on the headers it is sending, these are easily spoofed.  If I were you I would design your server software in such a way where by the client is irrelevant.

Comment: So I figured I'd go get myself an SSL certificate to make reading out the network a bit harder, which should hopefully deter others from even trying to figure out how the app is identifying itself and then just monitor the network for strange activity and block IPs (or patterns) that seem to be abusing the system. Does that sound right?

Answer (score 2):

> I would prefer to keep the data access limited (keep third parties from using my API). But how would I do this?
>
> ...
>
> the app itself must somehow verify that its the app sending the request, and not someone else.
>
> ...
>
> But how?

What you're asking for is not possible. It's also the wrong problem to solve.

Further reading: [Client Authenticity is not the Server's Problem](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem)

Answer (score 0):

You can't be 100% sure but you can make the reverse engineers work for it.

- use tls ao they can't easilly watch your protocol with a sniffer
- dont just use a single api key,  make the key a function of a variety of values spread through the app along with actual user data
- consider using the tls key sent by the server as part of the api key function so everything myateriously breaks if they mitm the tls
- use meaningless field names in the api
- push out updates frequently that change the api system